# Array push inside getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I use the following function as onclick event on an ahref link:

```
function checkOrgSaved() {
   var orgName = $.trim($("#orgName").val());
   var orgNames = new Array();

    $.getJSON("organizations?action=getOrganizations&onlyName=true&CSRFToken=" + csrf_token,   function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result.Orgs).length; i++) {
            var org = result.Orgs[i].name;
            orgNames.push(org);
        }
    });

    if ($.inArray(orgName, orgNames) == -1 || orgName == 0){
        alert("Foobar.");
        $("#editLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
    }
}
```

Like this, the `orgNames` array in the `if` statement is always empty. Why?

However if I declare the `orgNames` array inside the `getJSON` call and put the `if` statement also inside the `getJSON()` call, the array is filled correctly, but the line `$("#editLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");` does not work and a redirect is performed with a click on the ahref element.

What I'm trying to achieve is: If the orgName is empty or NOT in the orgNames array an JS alert should be thrown - without an redirect on the other page.

Comment: JS does not wait for async functions to finish, it will skip to your if block. Move your if block inside the getJSON below your for loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `$.getJSON` call is asynchronous, meaning the `if` statement will be executed **before** the JSON data is received and the callback is executed and `orgNames` is populated.

You might want to fetch the JSON and populate the array before the click occurs, and then just check agains the values:

```
var orgNames = new Array();

$.getJSON("organizations?action=getOrganizations&onlyName=true&CSRFToken=" + csrf_token,   function (result) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result.Orgs).length; i++) {
    var org = result.Orgs[i].name;
    orgNames.push(org);
  }
});

function checkOrgSaved() {
  var orgName = $.trim($("#orgName").val());

  if ($.inArray(orgName, orgNames) == -1 || orgName == 0){
    alert("Foobar.");
    $("#editLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
  }
}
```

This would also help avoid additional requests for the same JSON data.

Comment: That woks fine! Even with preventing the redirect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
    function checkOrgSaved() {
       var orgName = $.trim($("#orgName").val());
       var orgNames = new Array();
       $.getJSON("organizations?action=getOrganizations&onlyName=true&CSRFToken=" + csrf_token,   function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result.Orgs).length; i++) {
                var org = result.Orgs[i].name;
                orgNames.push(org);
            }
            if ($.inArray(orgName, orgNames) == -1 || orgName == 0){
              alert("Foobar.");
              $("#editLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
        }
        });   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass into `$.getJSON` as second parameter is a **callback that will be executed after the asynchronous HTTP call has been completed**.

The code after the `$.getJSON` is executed immediately, which means that the callback has most likely not run yet when you try to access the results via the array.

You have to move the logic that updates your UI into the callback function to ensure that the HTTP call has been completed when it is executed.

```
function checkOrgSaved() {
   var orgName = $.trim($("#orgName").val());
   var orgNames = new Array();

    $.getJSON("organizations?action=getOrganizations&onlyName=true&CSRFToken=" + csrf_token,   function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result.Orgs).length; i++) {
            var org = result.Orgs[i].name;
            orgNames.push(org);
        }

        if ($.inArray(orgName, orgNames) == -1 || orgName == 0){
            alert("Foobar.");
            $("#editLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
        }
    });
}
```

For more info, have a look [at jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Now my problem is like I mentioned above, the line `$("#editLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");` does not work anymore. A redirect is performed after a click on the ahref element.

Comment: `$("#editLink").attr("href", "#") ` couldn't you do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is an [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) language, right? What's happening is that your if statement runs before your get function's callback returns the result.

You should move your if check into the callback like this:

```
$.getJSON("organizations?action=getOrganizations&onlyName=true&CSRFToken=" + csrf_token, function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result.Orgs).length; i++) {
        var org = result.Orgs[i].name;
        orgNames.push(org);
    }
    if ($.inArray(orgName, orgNames) == -1 || orgName == 0) {
        alert("Foobar.");
        $("#editLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
    }
});
```